# Can't detect click function HighCharts plotLines & plotBands.events

Tags: javascript, function, highcharts

With these events below, I should be able to detect when the Plotlines or Plotbands are being mouseOvered and clicked in my app, however nothing happens :(

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.events

[**Docs example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-events/)

```
xAxis: [
    {
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { hour: '%l:%M%P' },
        id: 'main-x-axis',
        events: {
            setExtremes: prepareExtremes,
            afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'x-axis-alert',
        plotLines: [{
            id: 'alert-plotline',
            zIndex: 1001,
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    console.log('plotLines Click')
                },
                mouseover: function() {
                    console.log('plotLines hover')
                },
                mouseout: function() {
                    console.log('plotLines out')
                }
            }
        }],
        plotBands: [{
            id: 'alert-plotband',
            zIndex: 1001,
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    console.log('plotBands clicked!');
                },
                mouseover: function() {
                    console.log('plotBands hover')
                },
                mouseout: function() {
                    console.log('plotBands out')
                }
            }
        }],
        linkedTo: 0,
        showEmpty: false,
        lineWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: 'transparent',
        labels: { enabled: false }
    }],
series [{
        {
    id: 'priceline',
    name: 'price',
    showInLegend: false,
    zIndex: 1,
    color: '#4C73FF',
    data: [],
    dataGrouping: { enabled: false },
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function(event) {
                TooltipFactory.updateToolTipPoints('price', event.target);
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    id: 'alert-series',
    name: 'alert',
    yAxis: 'y-axis-alert',
    xAxis: 'x-axis-alert',
    data: [],
    color: 'rgba(254,235,236,0.1)',
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    showInLegend: false,
    dataGrouping: { enabled: false },
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function (event) {
                console.log('alert-series clicked!');
            }
        }
    }
}
}]
```

---

The only mouse actions I can detect are in the `TooltipFactory.formatTooltip` and `chartClick` functions below.

Also the chartClick only activates when you click on the points of the blue line graph.

[image]

```
vm.config = {
    global: { useUTC : false },
    options: {
        ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#474747',
            title: { text: '' },
            subtitle: { text: '' },
            renderTo: 'chart1',
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                load: () => {}
            }
        },
        rangeSelector: {enabled: false},
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            formatter: function(tooltipObj) {
                return TooltipFactory.formatTooltip(tooltipObj, this.points);
            }
        },
        exporting: {enabled: false},
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                turboThreshold: 0,
                    events: {
                        click: chartClick
                    }
            },
            area:   { stacking: 'normal' },
            column: { stacking: 'normal ' }
        }
    },
```

The chartClick function:

```
const chartClick = e => {
    console.log('chartClick',e);
    let extremes  = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
    let endDate   = Math.round(e.point.category / 1000);
    let startDate = Math.round(extremes.min / 1000);
    $scope.$emit("timestamp.clicked", endDate, startDate);
};
```

Comment: You create empty plotBands/plotLines, without any from/to/y values, so plotBand/plotLine is created, but not placed on the chart. So there's no element which should fire any of your events. See demos for [plotBands](http://jsfiddle.net/xr9rw95t/) and [plotLines](http://jsfiddle.net/b3L18jz6/) - from/to/y are defined so you can see the line/band on the chart.

Comment: Ah sorry I just added my Series so you can see.

Comment: I didn't mean Series, but values for plotLine/plotBand :) See the sample you posted (from API) and compare with your options.

Comment: Thanks guys! New question about getting the point clicked posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088683/highchart-how-to-get-exact-point-timestamp-from-plotbands-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the area where PlotBands and PlotLines are added to our graph:

```
const formatPlotBand = _.curry((color, alert) => {
    return {
        color : color,
        from  : toMilliseconds(alert.start_epoch),
        to    : toMilliseconds(alert.end_epoch),
        id    :'alert-plotband',
        events: {
            click: function(e) {
                console.log('this',this)
                console.log('alert-plotband Clicked', e);
            },
            mouseover: function(e) {
                let target = {
                    name: alert.term,
                    type: alert.type,
                    percent: Math.floor(alert.percent_change)
                }
                TooltipFactory.updateToolTipPoints('alert', target);
            },
            mouseout: function(e) {
                let target = {
                    name: '',
                    type: '',
                    percent: ''
                }
                TooltipFactory.updateToolTipPoints('alert', target);
            }
        }
    }
});

const renderChartAlerts = _.curry((chart, alertObjects) => {
    let plotLineData, plotBandData, alertSeriesData, xAxis, alertSeries;

    xAxis = chart.get('x-axis-alert');
    alertSeries = chart.get('alert-series');

    alertSeriesData = _.map(alertObjects, prepareAlertSeries);
    plotLineData    = formatPlotLine(chart, 'rgba(254,235,236,0.5)');
    plotBandData    = formatPlotBand('rgba(254,235,236,0.1)');

    plotLineData    = _.map(alertObjects, plotLineData);
    plotBandData    = _.map(alertObjects, plotBandData);

    alertSeries.setData(alertSeriesData);

    _.each(plotLineData, (lineData, index) => {
        xAxis.addPlotLine(lineData);
        xAxis.addPlotBand(plotBandData[index]);
    });

    return chart;
});
```

Now I can use this `click` function below, having a problem however not able to find the exact point I clicked on. There isn't a `points` key. Oh well that may be another question.

Sorry the way our app is structured, made it too complex for a simple jsFiddle example to work.